# create oscillator with variable frequency by computer

Tags: microcontroller, oscillator

How can I use my computer to control the frequency of a variable oscillator?

THANK YOU.

Comment: This is a community forum, answers should be posted here and not emailed to your personal email address, the questions and answers on this site are made public for the benefit of everyone

Comment: @ VAHID - In order to answer your question properly it would help if you gave some more details. For example - Do you have an oscillator circuit in mind? Are you looking for a software based solution? Do you plan to use a micro controller with your project? Do you have any particular application in mind for your project?

Comment: Since the original post asked for emails, I emailed him to check that he was not waiting for emails and would come back and add information. If he fails to add more details it would seem this question is too vague.

Comment: @Korkut - Agreed, It's possible they're just fishing for email addresses and aren't really bothered about an answer, it could explain the lack of information or follow up.

Answer (score 4):

1. Specify a frequency range.

   - If you only want 20 Hz to 20 kHz you can use the sound card built into most computers. It usually has at least 2 channels, sometimes more.
2. Specify a type of waveform.

   - A sound card can output almost any waveform but the output is ac coupled, so you can't offset it with a dc level.
3. Specify the amplitude.

   - The output from a sound card is in the range of 1Vp-p to 2Vp-p, this may be okay for some situations but not all.

Comment: http://www.sillanumsoft.org/ has an oscilloscope / waveform generator that can output a sine wave to the sound card with whatever frequency you want

Comment: He specifically said that it needs to control a variable oscillator, not be a variable oscillator.

Comment: What would be the fundamental difference? (apart from this external oscillator probably being much more powerful.)

Comment: I would have to see what he has. He could have a chip that has SPI that you are able to set its frequency with. His question is very vague in this sense.

Comment: In which case he could use an FTDI chip and communicate with an MCU on the same board as his oscillator IC...

Comment: Excuse me for the lack of tact - But I don't think English is VAHID's first language, and I have heavily formatted their question to try make sense of it - therefore it's probably necessary to request more information before the question can be answered properly.

Comment: Yes, that is a very large fundamental difference though, which is my original point.

Comment: There are also VCO that when you vary a DC voltage the oscillator has a variance in frequency, this is something I know many people attempt to use a computer to control.

Comment: The output of a sound card is ac coupled so VAHID would need to modify a sound card to get it to work.